# Cypress - use of regular expression in 'contains' function returning no match

Tags: javascript, regex, cypress

Cypress is supposed to allow regular expressions in its 'contains' function, but it is finding no match, whereas there are a lot of elements containing the search text. I have to put in the full name to allow it to find it - but I want to get all the elements with names starting with 'Tier2_Forest' not just one.

For instance, this works:

```
cy.get('#database-col')
  .find('div.el-row div.card header.card-header p.card-header-title')
  .contains('Tier2_Forest : Tier2_Forest_ManEvents')
  .as('dbCard');
```

But this doesn't:

```
cy.get('#database-col')
  .find('div.el-row div.card header.card-header p.card-header-title')
  .contains('Tier2_Forest')
  .as('dbCard');
```

Have also unsuccessfully tried it in the format recommended by Cypress for regex - i.e. line starts with that phrase:
`contains(/^Tier2_Forest/)`

For some reason when I use `contains('.db')` it returns a list of elements containing '.db' at the **end** of their names - but I don't want those...
Snippet of the generated DOM:

[[image: Generated DOM]]

Comment: I nowhere see `Tier2_Forest_ManEvents` in that picture (text would be better), only `Tier2_Forest Man Events`. On top that represents the rendered DOM, not the actual source of the page - those things can still differ.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are on the right track, but `.contains(/^Tier2_Forest/)` fails because the text is not at the beginning of the string, there is white space preceding it.

Just try `.contains(/Tier2_Forest/)`

or more precisely `.contains(/\s*Tier2_Forest/)`

where \s* matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

Check it out in https://regex101.com

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately Hiram, these do indeed work as regular expressions but don't work in Cypress.

Comment: Yep, it works with `.contains(/Tier2_Forest/)` but not with `.contains(/^Tier2_Forest/)`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:
It takes into account spaces and line breaks if there are any.

```js
.contains(/^\s*\n?Tier2_Forest/) // check begins, with nothing before
.contains(/^\s*\n?Tier2_Forest : Forest Database\s*\n?$/) //exact same sentence, check nothing before, check nothing after
```